# Without Stokes's Theorem - Calculate $\iint_S \operatorname{curl} \mathbf{F} \cdot\; d\mathbf{S}$ for $\mathbf{F} = (-y^3,x^3,z^3)$ - 2012 9C

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, proof-explanation

**Question:** 2012 9C. Consider the (cutoff) paraboloid defined by $z= x^2 + y^2 , \frac{1}{9} \le z \le 1$. Sketch the surface. 
Verify Stokes’s Theorem for for $\mathbf{F} = (-y^3,x^3,z^3)$.

Herein, I enquire only about directly computing $ \iint_S (\nabla × F )· d\mathbf{S}$, which I separate from the computation [with Stokes's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/781386/53259).

**My effort:** Parameterise with $\mathbf{z} (x,y) = ( x, y, x^2 + y^2 )$
Then $\mathbf{\nabla × F} = (0, 0, 3(x^2 + y^2))$.
I think that S is supposed to be the projection of $ x^2 + y^2 \le 1/9 $ onto z = 0 plane.

> $1.$ This guess proved correct, but why is this S? Why isn't S the projection of $ x^2 + y^2 \le 1 $ or something else ? Why must it be projected onto the z = 0 plane? Why not somewhere else?

♦ denote objects that don't need to be computed because they're dot-producted with 0.

$ \iint_{S} (\nabla × F ) · {\mathbf{n}} \, dS = \iint_{ x^2 + y^2 \le z, 1/9 \le z \le 1  } (\nabla × F ) \cdot {\mathbf{n}} \, dA 
\\ = \iint_{ x^2 + y^2 \le z, 1/9 \le z \le 1 } (0, 0, 3(x^2 + y^2)) \cdot (-\partial_x \mathbf{z}, -\partial_y \mathbf{z},1) \, dA
\\ = \iint_{ x^2 + y^2 \le z, 1/9 \le z \le 1 } (0, 0, 3\color{orangered}{(x^2 + y^2)}) \cdot (♦, ♦,1) \, dA.$

> $2.$ How would one determine that it's $\color{green}{(\partial_{x} \mathbf{z} \times \partial_{y} \mathbf{z}} )$ that 'produces the outward normal which is what we want', and not $\color{darkred}{(\partial_{y} \mathbf{z}  \times \partial_{x} \mathbf{z} )}$?
>   I know that everything must be positively oriented by convention. If the answer is geometric or visual, would you please provide a picture?

Conver tot polar coordinates, where $ z = radius^2 = 1/9  \implies radius = 1/3 $.
Then above = $ 3 \int^{2\pi}_{0} \, d\theta  \int^{1}_{1/3} \color{orangered}{r^2} \, r \, dr  \, d\theta  = 3 \cdot 2\pi \cdot \frac{1}{4} (1^4 - (1/3)^4) = 40\pi/27.   $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the normal you have $\frac{\partial \mathbf{z}}{\partial x}=(1,0,2x), \quad\frac{\partial \mathbf{z}}{\partial y}=(0,1,2y)$ so $$\frac{\partial \mathbf{z}}{\partial x}\times \frac{\partial \mathbf{z}}{\partial y}=(-2x,-2y,1)$$ So you were correct that the normal is $(-\partial_x\mathbf{z},-\partial_y\mathbf{z},1)=(-2x,-2y,1)$.

So the direct computation gives $$\iint_S \nabla\times\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{S}=\iint_S 3(x^2+y^2)\,\mathrm{d}A=\iint_S3r^3\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta$$ where I have switched to polar as you did. Your error here was with the region of integration $S$. We have $1/9\le z\le 1$ so $$1/9\le x^2+y^2=r^2\le 1\implies 1/3\le r\le 1$$ Therefore we get for the integral $$3\cdot{1\over 4}(2\pi)(1^4-(1/3)^4)=\frac{3\pi}{2}\frac{80}{81}=\frac{40\pi}{27}$$

---

**EDIT:** $1.$ To determine the region $S$, you need to look at *what your parameters range between* to span out $S$. In this case, the parameters are the two variables $x$ and $y$. When $z$ goes from $1/9$ to $1$, this means that $x,y$ cover the region *between* two circles of radius $1/3$ and $1$. If you switch to polar coords, which is equivalent to making the substitutions $$x=r\cos\theta \\ y=r\sin\theta$$ then the region can be expressed nicely as $S=\{(r,\theta): 1/3\le r\le 1,\;0\le\theta\le 2\pi\}$.

$2.$ Determining which direction the normal should take is, as you surmised, entirely a geometric matter. In this case, the problem only says to "verify Stokes' Theorem" so it does not specify the direction of the normal. We get to choose. I took the normal as $(-2x,-2y,1)$. Note that the $z$-component is *positive*, so the normal faces up. If you imaging (or graph) a paraboloid, you will see that the *inward* normal points *up*, and the *outward* normal faces *down*. Therefore this vector, which points up, must be the inward normal. If points to the inside the paraboloid instead of to the outside.

To apply Stokes' Theorem by using a line integral(s) over the boundary circles (when $z=1/9$ and when $z=1$) you have to orient them consistently with this choice of normal (remember, I chose arbitrarily - but in this step we don't have any freedom to choose). I will explain this in the other post.

---

*Second part was successfully moved, apparently there was a period when nobody could answer questions which is why I was getting an error message.*

Comment: `\oint`? $\displaystyle\oint_C f(z)\,dz$.

Comment: @kahen Thank you that's what I was looking for!

Comment: I can't seem to post to your other question. And as to this post, you can _always_ parameterize functions as $(x,y,f(x,y))$ you just have to make sure that you handle everything correctly.

Comment: @LePressentiment See your other post and my edit.

Comment: +1. Thank you again. Were you able to answer my question 2? Please advise if you mind my ancillary edit just now, where I numbered your answer to my $1.$

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the delay. Why can we choose which normal? I took $(-2x,-2y,1)$ because the z-component of this $= 1$, which is positive. So this means the normal points outwards, which is the definition of + orientation?