# When and why must we parameterise $f(x, y) = ...$ with variables besides $x, y$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, parametric, proof-explanation

For [10C](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/740996/53259), my choice of parameterisation $\mathbf{r} (x,y) = ( x, y, z(x, y))$ fails to effect the right answer, but that of user ellya does function.

Yet for [9C](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/781417/53259), the parameterisation $\mathbf{r} (x,y) = ( x, y, z(x, y))$ does function. Nonetheless, in my first attempt, I didn't realise its legitimacy and had thought that it also failed. But in reality, the failure was due to my  algebraic errors. I did compute the right answer by 
virtue of the parameterisation: $\mathbf{r} (\theta, z) = ( \sqrt{z} \cos \theta, \sqrt{z} \sin \theta, z)$ for all $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi, 1/9 \le z \le 1$. But this is  much harder than need be; it wastes more time and effort and complicates the calculations.

$1.$ Why do we need to parameterise for these questions? How would we determine that we must?

$2.$ When does the parameterisation $\mathbf{r} (x,y) = ( x, y, z(x, y))$ function? When doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we must parametrize because if we integrate over a paraboloid or a cyclinder we have restrictions that cannot be expressed in form $(x,y,f(x,y))$.

For instance the unit cylinder needs $x^2+y^2= 1$ if we try to write $(x,y,z)$ on the domain $[0,1]\times[0,1]\times[0,1]$ we end up including point that do not satisfy $x^2+y^2= 1$ for instance the point $(1,1,0)$, but if we put:

$(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,z)$, the $x$ and $y$ values are now forced to satisfy $x^2+y^2=1$, since $x^2+y^2=cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$.

We need to parametrize if our domain is non rectangular.

Comment: Thanks. I don't perceive your first paragraph. Would you separate the ideas? What are the 'restritions'?

Comment: The restrictions are that our $(x,y)$ domain must satisfy $x^2+y^2=1$

Comment: Thanks. What's the $xy$ value? And would you please enlarge on why "we end up including point that do not satisfy ..." ?

Comment: Will you please to respond  in your answer, and not as comments?

Comment: Thanks. Would you be able to answer my other questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/738149/53259 and 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739235/theta-for-triple-integral-above-paraboloid-z-x2-y2-and-below-z-2y ?